# Pushing object with observable properties in observable array still track object's propteries.

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an object `addItem` with several observable properties. Once the properties are populated I push this into an observable array `allItems` that tracks all the object created during a session.

The problem is that when I push an `addItem` into the `allItems` and then make changes to the `addItem`; `allItems` also changes. I assumed that once `addItem` was pushed into `allItems` the binding between the two would be no more, but it seem like a push just adds a reference.

How can I add `addItem` to `allItems` without the reference?

Comment: Can you show some code? But in general you have to copy your properties yourself...

Comment: If you don't want allItems to receive a notification because one of the items changed, and then send an update because of it, you just need a simple array, not an observable array, no ?

Comment: @Jalayn, a `ko.observableArray' will only notify when the actual array changes (i.e. items are added, removed, or replaced).  If a property on the item changes, the observable array doesn't track those changes, so array subscribers will not be notified.

Comment: @JosephGabriel you're right of course, I didn't understand what's the problem with keeping a reference... unless he just wants a copy or a hash of the object, and if that's the case then your answer is certainly correct.

Comment: no worries :) I probably misunderstood your comment.  I find it's a common misunderstanding with updating object properties on objects within observable arrays, so I figured the more times it's stated the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ko.observable` items will still be observable after they are added to an array.  If you want to remove the observability, you'll need to create an object with non-observable properties.

One way is to copy the properties by hand, using `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(obj.prop)`.

A more "automatic" way is to use `ko.toJS()` - this will convert an object with observable properties into a plain JS object.

```
self.allItems.push(ko.toJS(self.item2));
```

or if you want to maintain the observability separately for items inside the array, you can readd it using `ko.mapping.fromJS`:

```
allItems.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(self.item2)));
```

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/PSn9y/)